# sql select within dates from each other

Tags: sql-server

[image]I am trying to select all the B types within 12 months of each other.

[image]

This is what the table looks like. I need to select all type B s that are within 12 months. In this case, 5,4, and 3.

Here is the SQL to create the table, just in case.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_ads]
(
    [id] [int] NULL,
    [dateStamp] [date] NULL,
    [type] [char](1) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ads] ([id], [dateStamp], [type]) 
VALUES (1, CAST(0x61370B00 AS Date), N'b')

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ads] ([id], [dateStamp], [type]) 
VALUES (2, CAST(0x01380B00 AS Date), N'a')

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ads] ([id], [dateStamp], [type]) 
VALUES (3, CAST(0x52380B00 AS Date), N'b')

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ads] ([id], [dateStamp], [type]) 
VALUES (4, CAST(0x73380B00 AS Date), N'b')

INSERT [dbo].[tbl_ads] ([id], [dateStamp], [type]) 
VALUES (5, CAST(0xDA380B00 AS Date), N'b')
```

I don't want to use any cursors. How do I accomplish this?

thanks in advance.

EDIT: I apologize for creating confusion. Img 2 is a better explanation of what I am trying.

In this case, I'd include id=5 and id=3.

It's like a bubble sort and then pick only records that are within 365days.

Comment: Your problem is not well-defined.  What if they are Jan1, May1, and Aug 1.  Are these within 6 months?  How would they be grouped?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff If date1 is within 12 months of date2 then select, if date2 is within 12 months of date 3 then select. does it make sense?

Comment: can you add an example output? should the result be records: 3, 4, and 5, or should it be 3 records with the dates that fall within the 6 months range? 3 | 4, 5 4 | 3, 5 5 | 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cross join` in this case

Query:

```
select * from #tbl A
cross join #tbl B
where DATEDIFF(DD,A.dateStamp,B.dateStamp) between 0 and 365
and A.id<>B.id
and A.type='b'
and B.type='b'
order by A.dateStamp
```

Result:

```
id  dateStamp   type    id  dateStamp   type
1   2013-07-25  b   3   2014-03-23  b
1   2013-07-25  b   4   2014-04-25  b
3   2014-03-23  b   4   2014-04-25  b
3   2014-03-23  b   5   2014-08-06  b
4   2014-04-25  b   5   2014-08-06  b
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
from [tbl_ads] 
where type='b' and 
dateStamp Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(4) ,(year(getDate())-1))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2) ,month(getDate()))+'-'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2) ,day(getDate())) AND getDate()
```

This might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but this does not return what I need. It returns only one record.